# Setting c++11 std for gcc in solaris 11

Tags: c++11, gcc, makefile, solaris, cflags

I am trying to install cmake on solaris machine by building its source code. In  one of the steps we need to do "make" to build the source code. When I do a make I am getting below error

```
/json_reader.cpp:35:18: error: ‘snprintf’ is not a member of ‘std’
#define snprintf std::snprintf
```

This indicates that code is using c++11 std but gcc compiler uses c++98 std. I have gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC) in the solaris machine. As per my knowledge make is wrapper over gcc.

Question is: How to set CFLAGS for gcc globally so that when I do a "make" it directly uses `c++ 11 std`.

Comment: "This indicates that code is using c++11 std but gcc compiler uses c++98 std."—How's that? cppref only contains one overload of `snprintf` introduced in 11, others were present before that (dragged happily from C). More likely it indicates <cstdio> somehow did not get included in this file.

Comment: Tried including <cstdio>, but the error is still the same. As you have mentioned the file included only <stdio.h> header file. So included <cstdio> as well but still getting the same error. :(

Comment: *How to set `CFLAGS` for gcc globally so that when I do a "make" it directly uses c++ 11 std.*  You **don't**.  `CFLAGS` is "**C** flags", not "C++ flags".  You likely want `CXXFLAGS`